# Animação de input no background Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Caros, gostaria de fazer o seguinte.

Tenho dois botões, um interfere o valor do outro. 
Quando um campo for alterado quero que o outro campo ganhe um background e vai voltando com o background ao normal, com uma determinada animação em poucos segundos.

***Estou usando JQUERY 3.1.1***

Comment: Você já possui algo? Explique um pouco mais o que deseja, o que já possui, etc. Desta forma será mais fácil alguém conseguir lhe ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pode usar **.animate()** pra isso. Adicione o script "**jquery-ui.js**"

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  $('#btn2').animate({
    backgroundColor: '#000000'
  }, 1000, function() {
    $('#btn2').animate({
      backgroundColor: ''
    }, 1500)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id=btn1>
  TESTE
</button>
<button id=btn2>
  RESULTADO
</button>
```